# Mouse Teleop TurtleSim

Tags: ros, teleop, turtlesim, turtlesim-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To whom it may concern,

I have managed to work turtlesim with the turtlesim_teleop_node using a keyboard but require to turn using mouse control.

i have tried to find the method and cannot find one on the internet. I know that ROS has an inbuilt mouse_teleop and i am trying to integrate it with turtlesim.

Any help?

---

**EDIT**

I have tried GitHub Repo and other Ros repositories which i found:

- https://github.com/ros-teleop/teleop_tools
- https://github.com/clayauld/clearpath-ros-teleop

but was still unable to figure out how to work it with turtlesim.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277288/mouse-teleop-turtlesim/) by [RosStudent](https://answers.ros.org/users/32856/rosstudent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-12-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosStudent](https://answers.ros.org/users/32856/rosstudent/) on 2017-12-05**:
any help ? :/

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-12-05**:
Have you tried Google? https://www.google.de/search?q=ros%20mouse_teleop

within the first few hits: GitHub Repo, rosindex, ...

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-12-06**:
please edit your question, don't post additional Information as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you have to work through the [Getting Started](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/StartGuide) page and [ROS tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) and try to understand those. And especially [this Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch#Using_roslaunch) about roslaunch.

I don't know on which Topic the turtlebot is listening, but it is most probably not `mouse_vel` which you would publish on if you use the [Launch file in `mouse_teleop`](https://github.com/ros-teleop/teleop_tools/blob/indigo-devel/mouse_teleop/launch/mouse_teleop.launch).
You should probably remap to `teleop_velocity_smoother/raw_cmd_vel`as they are doing in all the Launch files  [here](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/tree/kinetic/turtlebot_teleop/launch).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0